How to setup Application Insight on Next.js 15 in Client and Server Side Rendering
I have tried countless different solutions to setup Application Insight working on latest Next.Js 15 version but with no success. Crawled whole internet with different blog posts and articles with no success. All solutions I found do not work on next.js 15 version easily, as by default everything is Server Side Rendering unless you write "use client" on page.tsx. Has anyone managed to get Application Insight working on next.js15 canary version and if yes, how? In azure I managed to connect App Insight to static web app and that collects basic information like page tracking. But if I throw error on SSR, it does not collect that error with message to AppInsight. In Summary, I'm using package "15.0.0-canary.65" and I'm running it in Azure Static Web App.
I have also setup instrumentation.ts file on root of the project, then used this stackoverflow post examples to setup Application Insight but I get errors that I have duplicate instances of AppInsights: How to use Azure application insights with nextjs app
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/instrumentation

Jon Koivula Are you looking for this.

Did you find a solution @Jon Koivula?
